# Did Yuri Gagarin end up in critical condition after coming back to Earth due to the missing magnetic field?

Tags: space-flight

My friend's mother is about to undergo some treatment in magnetic field therapy for osteoarthritis and he is trying to verify if this is useful as claimed, or if this has any harmful effects. The [website](http://sbfhealthcare.com/itworks/) of their institution claims that:

> In Yuri Gagarin’s historic flight to space, he returned in near
>   critical condition after only one hour and forty-eight minutes in
>   space. Clearly, there was some vital element missing in space that we
>   receive on earth. Yuri had plenty of food, water and oxygen and since
>   the flight was less than 2 hours, he only needed oxygen. The critical
>   missing element appears to be the earth’s magnetic field. Since that
>   first flight, pulsed magnetic devices have been used in every space
>   suit and space station. Further studies have been done on earth (zero
>   field studies) with both laboratory animals and human subjects.

Did he really end up in critical condition as it is claimed? Was it verified that this was due to the missing magnetic field?

Comment: *pulsed magnetic devices have been used in every space suit and space station* is a blatant lie.

Comment: Magnetic therapy will have exactly as many harmful effects as helpful ones: zero.

Comment: @hdhondt Transcranial magnetic stimulation is a legitimate diagnostic tool ... but I share your skepticism for this particular treatment.

Comment: FWIW: *The page is blocked by Bitdefender Endpoint Security Tools Cloud (Malware)* when I tried to go to that website. It's fishy anyway, hugedomains.com says the domain is for sale.

Comment: Disregard that last 'for sale' remark in my previous comment. I made a typo *sbhealthcare.com* when investigating the domain.

Comment: Purely anecdotal: I've once spend three hours in the absence of the earth's magnetic field while sitting in an [actively shielded chamber of an MEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoencephalography#Magnetic_shielding). I felt quite fine. :)

Comment: @JanDoggen re "pulsed magnetic devices", do you have any more info about that, or anything that might warrant posting an answer?

Comment: The effects of EMF on the human body are not well understood. Space travel has nothing to do it.

Comment: @hdhondt just to nitpick, magnetic therapy might have negative effects if you have magnetic metal in your body.

Comment: @hdhondt Actually magnetotherapy seems to have (little, but still...) anti-inflammatory capabilities. I studied the effect of the eletromagnetic fields on the human body, and this is what I recall from a research I did years ago.

Comment: @wjandrea No. As DevSolar wrote in his/her answer *Proving non-existence is hard*. But I don't know even *one* anecdote of them having been used. And don't forget that if someone writes these things the proof is *on them* - I don't feel the need to start investigating this.

Comment: Well, in the broadest sense, a loudspeaker is a "pulsed magnetic device," so one could argue there exists one "in every space suit and space station." Not for the reason implied, but still not a lie.

Comment: This same claim appears in the text of [US9278231 B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US9278231), published 2016-02-08 (and initially submitted in an application around 2010).

Comment: @Dubu It doesn't seem reasonable to interpret a statement's meaning independently of its context, though it's a funny observation.

Comment: "Yuri had plenty of food"? Did they pack food into a 2 hrs trip?

Comment: @Nat But purveyors of snake oil (not saying this company is such a purveyor) will take anything out of context if the result sounds right. Spacecraft/suits have speakers... therefore they have "pulsed magnetic devices". Note the original quote says "_Since that time pulsed-magnetic devices have been used in every space suit and space station._". It doesn't _actually claim_ that this is as a result of "lost magnetism" (although the juxtaposition might make some people think that was the reason).

Comment: @QuoraFeans - well, in this case "none" would be "plenty". :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis: no even a salami sandwich and an apple?

Comment: @TheMathemagician TMS is basically just inducing a current, but without needing to implant electrodes. The outputs aren't from Magnets! (jazz hands), they are from using a tool to poke your brain in specific ways.

Comment: @Dubu: In that case, their whole point would be wrong as also Yuri Gagarin’s suite had already "pulsed magnetic device" as his suite had loudspeakers, too. Hence it couldn't have been the magnetic field he was missing.

Comment: I smell snake oil

Comment: @Emil this is a different situation as for cosmic rays are already cut off. This applies to the OP question in a sense... Lack of magnetic field does not have the same consequences in different environments

Comment: I mean, an astronaut leaving Earth's magnetic field may well experience harm caused indirectly by the lack of a magnetic field, thanks to cosmic rays. That's not what they're talking about, though.

Answer (score 344, accepted):

Nuts.

[Vostok 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1) reached an Apogee of 327 km. That is **well** within Earth's [magnetosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Magnetosphere).

Aside from that, and aside from certain sensory effects that can be experienced [when exposed to *strong* magnetic fields](http://www.nytimes.com/1983/02/22/science/do-enormous-magnets-affect-the-human-body.html), the human body doesn't care much for magnetism, or the lack of it.

The one thing that would make a lack of magnetism in space harmful would be solar wind (which Earth's magnetic field deflects). Before you get that high, you'd pass through the [Van Allen radiation belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt), where the *presence* of Earth's magnetic field results in an *increase* of radiation.

Either way, "pulsed magnetic devices" in a space suit won't make a difference, and I seriously doubt they exist. (See comments -- they don't.)

---

In the end, the most competent person to answer these kind of questions would be a doctor, not the internet (or someone who would directly make money from a given therapy).

---

Post Scriptum:

I had a look at the website you linked. This one (from the "about us" page) is a howler:

> Till date over 6500 cases of Osteoarthritis have been treated...

Note that it says "treated", no mention on success rates.

> ...and clinical trials on terminally ill Cancer patients have been successfully completed.

The *trials* have been "successfully completed", but not a word about the results. I think if they had been curing "terminally ill Cancer patients", even just a couple of them, we would have heard about it in mainstream media for sure.

And I mean *mainstream* media, not the kind [they present on their website](http://sbfhealthcare.com/media/). My personal favourite there is [the *DNA Sunday* "article" which is *marked* "ADVI"](http://sbfhealthcare.com/media/picture3/) (advertisment). So they list one of their own advertisments as *media reference*?

Stay well clear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65656/discussion-on-answer-by-devsolar-did-yuri-gagarin-end-up-in-critical-condition-a).

Comment: The only thing that I don't get is why we need to know the astrological sign of these terminally ill patients. ;)

Comment: Poor English either way, you cannot treat a terminally ill patient, he or she is beyond treatment at that stage.

Comment: Well, I guess that they could mean to provoke remission on patients considered as terminally ill for regular (proven and usually somewhat efficient) therapies, but that would be blatant lies again?

Comment: Let's add: schematics of the [Apollo suit](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15193/103). They were definitely outside range of Earth's magnetosphere, and there's no "pulsed magnetic device" to be found anywhere within the schematics of the suits.

Comment: I am not saying that magnetic treatments is woo. I couldn't fin any evidence of them work eider. But still they are used on clinical treatments. Can some one explain that?

Comment: @NeilMeyer You can treat a terminally ill patient, for example giving them pain relief or other kinds of help. It's called [Palliative care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palliative_care).

Answer (score 194):

The part about magnetic fields has already been covered by [DevSolar's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/39438/39592). I will attempt to cover whether Yuri Gagarin was ever in "critical condition".

The Vostok 1's landing program consisted of the pilot [ejecting from the descent module when it was approx 7km above sea level](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/vostok1_landing.html), and parachuting to the ground alone. The descent module was designed to fall to the ground separately. This is independently reported [in multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1#Reentry_and_landing) [sources](https://www.space.com/16159-first-man-in-space.html).

Yuri Gagarin had to parachute down alone from 7km, successfully land, find the nearby villagers for assistance, and finally telephone Moscow for them to bring him back to the city. This shows that Gagarin was in reasonable health at that time, since this is pretty much impossible for someone who is "in critical condition", whatever definition they may use for that.

Comment: ...apart from that – the entire mission probably wasn't a picknick. Plenty of things you could attribute “critical condition” to, without resorting to magnetic fields...

Comment: Case in point, the referenced article mentions an "ejection seat", which likely means the occupant was subjected to a [fairly violent process](http://www.smh.com.au/national/education/how-dangerous-is-it-to-eject-from-a-fighter-jet-20120730-239mp.html).  Far more reasonable to attribute any health issues to that than to magnetism (or lack thereof).  To say nothing of the launch process itself, potential motion sickness, and/or mental stress from basically being a human guinea pig in an experiment that could easily kill you in any number of unpleasant ways.

Comment: @aroth Ejection seats are not inherently violent.  In an aircraft ejection they always are because they have to eject the person fast enough to clear control surfaces and with modern seats they're also built to allow a pilot to eject at the last second--you need to get away from the impending fireball.  A planned ejection from a falling capsule has no such need, it could be gentle.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - Yes, it could have been.  That's why I qualified by saying "likely".  It seems plausible, given the Russians were racing the U.S. to space, that they may have reused an existing ejection system rather than creating a purpose-built one.  However it's not clear from the references provided if that was the case or not; they just establish than an "ejection seat" was used.  More info regarding its design/specifications would be useful.

Comment: Early ejection systems might cause compression vertebral fractures indeed, because jettisons were used instead of combination of a jettison and a rocket in more recent developments. Gagarin was not known to have a vertebral fracture out of ejection. Regardless of politics, ejection systems are developed and tested on jet fighters, and also Gagarin might have been trained to use one being a military jet pilot. I doubt if anyone would risk a space mission with a new development for such a well-known and tested component.

Comment: Anyway, being parachuted 7km down, even with oxygen and space suit, may have proven challenging for the body, especially thermally, and system dysfunction may have put him in any sort of mess. Critical condition may have been him having some frost burn and so on. Nothing preventing him to contact back the base, but not something really pleasant anyway. But these are really suppositions. As stated by Tom under, it seems Gagarin was quite healthy at the end of the trip.

Comment: [History SE Question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40268/what-did-yuri-gagarin-do-while-waiting-for-his-ride/40307#40307) about the logistics of Yugi Gagarin's ride home from the farm after spaceflight.

Comment: @AndoJurai then again, he would hardly have any problem to set the internal temperature to any lower point, making exit at 7km less shocking. Jettisoning was pre-planned, so he had plenty of time to do that too, if needed.

Comment: @AndoJurai reading ru-wiki (if u want, do www.translate.ru over ru-wiki page for Gagarin ) now, it says: Gagarin was in a hermetic space-suit, the air-pipe with Vostok was disconnected ok, and this should had automatically open a valve, connecting suit insides with the air around him. It failed. Gagarin was somewhat suffocating and struggled to open a valve manually, he succeeded.  This I think shows that the suit was isolated really well and chill air inlet was relatively slow, making instant frostbites unlikely.

Comment: @Arioch Thanks for this precision (Blood and souls for you;)!)

Comment: One could say the condition of Yuri returning was mission critical. If you pull that through a translation engine often enough, I'm sure you can find something which vaguely resembles a critical condition...

Comment: @aroth he was an experienced militar pilot definitely it wouldnt do any thing to him

Comment: @Mast there is no direct copy of "mission critical" expression in Russian, so translating back and worth seems unlikely process here.

Answer (score 43):

In addition to everything else that was mentioned already, [according to this article](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/vostok1_landing.html), Gagarin reported back to headquarters that he was in good health shortly after landing.

There are also pictures of him not long after, apparently, as he is still in flight suit, e.g. here: https://bashny.net/t/es/140240 - and he seems to be perfectly fine.

Primary sources can probably be found on the Russian Internet. So if you care much, find a friend who speaks Russian.

Comment: Google Translate - мой друг, который плохо говорит по-русски.

Comment: Of course, in the propaganda climate of that time it's very well possible that these pictures are completely forged. (For instance, taken before takeoff and published later.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby - try www.translate.ru

Comment: @FedericoPoloni indeed, for example public videos of Gagarin starting reportedly were staged after his return. However, month after landing Gagarin was sent to over-the-world trip, to settle USSR triumph. For example 18 July 1961 he was in Cuba: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd0B-zyxrL4 . Now you may say, Cuba being USSR-friendly and USA-antagonistic could play into such a propaganda effort, but in the same very July Gagarin also visited London, UK. And UK would have little compel to suppress any health issues Gagarin could have.

Comment: Another side of the same coin, @FedericoPoloni , "in the propaganda climate of that time it's very well possible that" fake rumors about Gagarin health problems were intentionally created and disseminated to undermine USSR achievement. Compare today media wars around Syria

Answer (score 18):

Юрий Гагарин: "Я чувствовал себя хорошо..."

Yuri Gagarin: "I was feeling well ..."

If the "missing magnetic field" problem would be actual for Yuri Gagarin, who was in space for about an hour (1 hour and 48 minutes total flight time), how the extended missions for [Valeri Polyakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeri_Polyakov) could be possible?

> Valeri Vladimirovich Polyakov (Russian: Валерий Владимирович Поляков, born Valeri Ivanovich Korshunov on April 27, 1942) is a Russian former cosmonaut. He is the holder of the record for the longest single stay in space in human history, staying aboard the Mir space station for more than 14 months (437 days 18 hours) during one trip. His combined space experience is more than 22 months.

As for Yuri Gagarin, there were many reasons for him to return in a *nearly* critical conditions. Reported dynamic acceleration during gyrations on the reentry phase of that [flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1#Reentry_and_landing) was 8g, which is about maximum an average human can stand for extended period (more that few seconds).

Gagarin was *selected* and *trained* to stand dynamic acceleration. Just as other cosmonauts he was trained to stand the conditions which might well kill an average untrained man. Not only he stayed conscious all of the flight, he was reporting to earth during the flight, making records using paper and a tape recorder. He was also observing the navigation device "Взор" (Sight).

The last situation which could potentially be dangerous during the flight was right upon exiting the "Sharik" (little ball - the descent vehicle).
Gagarin described the ejection seat to carry him out of "Sharik":

> Так тихонько голову кверху повернул, и в этот момент выстрел — и я
>   катапультировался — быстро, хорошо, мягко, ничем не стукнулся.
>
> Подробнее см.: https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/19414/ (Наука и
>   жизнь, Юрий Гагарин: «Я чувствовал себя хорошо...» (Комментарий к
>   Главному полёту ХХ века))

"..and I was catapulted - fast, good and gently; did not hit anything".

The rest was parachuting descent from 7 kilometers.

After returning to earth atmosphere Gagarin could be able to participate in following activities:

- Struggling to reach the handle of breathing valve for 6 minutes while he was probably suffocating
- Safely grounding in 7 meters per second wind conditions (In my own experience that requires good physical mode).
- Walking
- Signaling to the people who saw him
- Contacting local military authorities
- Photographing with the locals
- Coordinating his own returning

It suggests he was not in a critical health state out of space trip by no means, whether it could be caused by missing magnetic field, weightlessness, homesickness or something else.

Comment: according to ru-wiki, Gagarin was in isolated space-suit, and after his catapulting (which broke air pipes connection with "Sharik") he found the valve opening the suit to atmosphere jammed. So he was suffocating, while emergently fixing the problem. So, "The rest was normal parachuting descent." is not absolutely so :-D

Comment: @Arioch Sure, edited to include that detail. It only confirms that by the time he returned he was good enough to stand that condition too, which was not arising from any virtual 'lack of magnetic field' in space.

Comment: Well, according to charlatans from OP, Valeri would already benefit from 'pulsed magnetic device' installed on the station or in his underwear.